# Broad and deep historical causes of gang violence in Mexico and El Salvador

Tags: latin-america

Rigth now, both Mexico and El Salvador seem to be either failed states or on the slippery slope toward becoming failed states. Some areas of Mexico are prosperous and orderly, but the US State Department has listed the states of Tamaulipas, Sinaloa, Colima, Michoacan and Guerrero as "do not travel areas," which puts them in the same class as Yemen and Syria. Although El Salvador's civil war is over, and it displays the forms of a multiparty democracy, they lose 0.5% of their population by emigration every year, an exodus demonstrating the extent to which society has broken down at the hands of gangs.

If you ask most people to name the historical causes of these breakdowns of social order, I think they would probably say that in Mexico, the cause of the problem is gangs supplying the US narcotics markets, while in El Salvador it's an outgrowth unhealed wounds from decades of left-right political polarization and civil war.

Is this accurate, or are there deeper causes?

El Salvador is one of the most overpopulated countries in the world, and [this article](https://www.capsweb.org/blog/nobody-ever-migrates-because-overpopulation) says:

> Trull blames the out-migration of so many young Salvadorans on the usual suspects: poverty, unemployment, gangs, violence and the long shadow of a brutal civil war in the 1980s. But not a word about overpopulation, which even back at the time of 1969’s short-lived “soccer war” between El Salvador and Honduras, more astute observers realized, was a contributing cause to the tensions between these two small republics that burst into warfare.
>
> Tiny El Salvador had five times the population density as Honduras. And for years, land-poor Salvadorans had been illegally migrating into Honduras and occupying Honduran lands; in other words, Honduras was serving as a safety valve for El Salvador, much as the U.S. does for both nations today.
>
> I have yet to see even one reporter in the mainstream media acknowledge rapid, unsustainable population growth in these Central American countries as an underlying cause of the mass migration taking place today.

However, if you look at the [population data](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/el-salvador-population/), El Salvador's population growth rate these days is comparable to that of the US. Although part of this is because there is so much emigration, the fertility rate seems to be at or below replacement. I don't know if this is the kind of normal reduction in fertility that often accompanies modernization and the education of women, or if it's the kind of reduction that we see in places like Russia, due to despair and economic hardship.

In Mexico, if you look at the [map of violence](https://www.mercurynews.com/2018/01/10/map-mexicos-worst-places-to-travel-according-to-the-state-department/) and compare it to the [map of population density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mexican_states_by_population_density), you actually seem to get somewhat of an anticorrelation. E.g., Puebla state is a lovely and peaceful place that I've enjoyed visiting recently, and it's also very densely populated, while a lot of the most violence-plagued areas in the north have low population densities. However, what may be more relevant is the population in proportion to resources and wealth, and the employment prospects of young men. Perhaps the map of violence is really a map of proximity to US drug markets.

How accurate would it be to assign blame to the following historical causes of the violence in these countries? --

- overpopulation
- history of poorly functioning political institutions (including very negative US historical actions in El Salvador)
- US drug market and drug prohibition policies, and the power of the narcotics trade to corrupt police and government
- low education and literacy

Are gangs like MS13 in El Salvador fundamentally drug gangs supplying the US market, or do they function mainly as the institutions of warlordism within El Salvador?

Comment: I think this belongs more suitably on [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Could you explain why? It's a question about history, although some of it is fairly recent history.

Comment: I thought the question should be reviewed for topicality.  The distinction between politics and history is often arbitrary, and the community should decide which side of the line this question falls on. There is also a decision to be made as to whether it is too broad. Let's see the result.

Comment: I agree with Pieter Geerkens "The distinction between politics and history is often arbitrary", and the question is perhaps also too broad. Not voting to close for now as I think a little editing / rephrasing can bring this on topic.

Comment: As so often I really do not see why people bother objecting to the question and wish they would channel their energies into trying to answer it, even if only partially, if they have sufficient relevant knowledge, which I regret I do not in this case. It seems an interesting and important question and may well involve taking quite a long historical perspective.

Answer (score 4):

> If you ask most people to name the historical causes of these breakdowns of social order, I think they would probably say that in Mexico, the cause of the problem is gangs supplying the US narcotics markets, while in El Salvador it's an outgrowth unhealed wounds from decades of left-right political polarization and civil war.
>
> Is this accurate, or are there deeper causes?

Not a specialist, but insofar as I'm aware this is inaccurate in both cases.

---

### El Salvador / MS-13

The gang basically [began in Los Angeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-13), and then spread to El Salvador - and Mexico - when gang members got deported from the US.

> The Mara Salvatrucha gang originated in Los Angeles, set up in the 1980s by Salvadoran immigrants in the city's Pico-Union neighborhood who immigrated to the United States after the Central American civil wars of the 1980s.
>
> Originally, the gang's main purpose was to protect Salvadoran immigrants from other, more established gangs of Los Angeles, who were predominantly composed of Mexicans and African-Americans.
>
> Many Mara Salvatrucha gang members from the Los Angeles area have been deported after being arrested. For example, Jose Abrego, a high-ranking member, was deported four times. As a result of these deportations, members of MS-13 have recruited more members in their home countries. The Los Angeles Times contends that deportation policies have contributed to the size and influence of the gang both in the United States and in Central America. According to the 2009 National Gang Threat Assessment, "The gang is estimated to have 30,000 to 50,000 members and associate members worldwide, 8,000 to 10,000 of whom reside in the United States.

---

### Mexican Drug cartels

In Mexico, the history is longer and the gangs/cartels are indeed [related to drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Drug_War). But it's at least in part tied to the DEA becoming more efficient at blocking Colombian cartels from smuggling cocaine through Florida.

> Given its geographic location, Mexico has long been used as a staging
> and transshipment point for narcotics and contraband between Latin
> America and U.S. markets. Mexican bootleggers supplied alcohol to the
> United States gangsters throughout the duration of the Prohibition in
> the United States, and the onset of the illegal drug trade with the
> U.S. began when the prohibition came to an end in 1933. Towards the
> end of the 1960s, Mexican narcotic smugglers started to smuggle drugs
> on a major scale.
>
> During the 1970s and early 1980s, Colombia's Pablo Escobar was the
> main exporter of cocaine and dealt with organized criminal networks
> all over the world. When enforcement efforts intensified in South
> Florida and the Caribbean, the Colombian organizations formed
> partnerships with the Mexico-based traffickers to transport cocaine
> through Mexico into the United States.
>
> This was easily accomplished because Mexico had long been a major
> source of heroin and cannabis, and drug traffickers from Mexico had
> already established an infrastructure that stood ready to serve the
> Colombia-based traffickers. By the mid-1980s, the organizations from
> Mexico were well-established and reliable transporters of Colombian
> cocaine. At first, the Mexican gangs were paid in cash for their
> transportation services, but in the late 1980s, the Mexican transport
> organizations and the Colombian drug traffickers settled on a
> payment-in-product arrangement.
>
> Transporters from Mexico usually were given 35% to 50% of each cocaine
> shipment. This arrangement meant that organizations from Mexico became
> involved in the distribution, as well as the transportation of
> cocaine, and became formidable traffickers in their own right.
> Currently, the Sinaloa Cartel and the Gulf Cartel have taken over
> trafficking cocaine from Colombia to the worldwide markets.

---

If memory serves me well there are a few pretty good documentaries floating around on the two topics. [This one by Vice on MS-13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGG7lRJJkJk), for instance, might catch your interest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. *The gang basically began in Los Angeles, and then spread to El Salvador - and Mexico - when gang members got deported from the US.* I don't think this really addresses the question of why gangs like this one have been able to effectively destroy the social order in El Salvador. There are Chinese gangs in the US, but they were never able to go back to China and bring the government to its knees.

Comment: @BenCrowell: There's a lot of poverty and corruption in Mexico and the rest of Central America than in the US. FWIW I always chuckle when Americans complain about corruption at home. Clearly they've never met a Mexican police officer who expects a kickback to spare you from an unjustified ticket, or an African customs official who can't possibly find your "lost" luggage but suddenly finds it when you give them a generous tip. (As to China, it has a thousands of years long tradition of having a bureaucracy around.)